# Finding missed spaces between words in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I'm editing a lot of text in word and i'm trying to use "find & replace" to see if i have missed any spaces between sentences. e.g. "The fox jumped over the fence.The fox went to sleep." I can't seem to find anyway to search that in word (without word finding all the new paragraphs).

Comment: Usually "Review" menu -> "Spelling and grammar" would find that problem for you.

Comment: Usually it does but I've found a few times that it didn't, i was trying to see if i could search using "find & replace"

Comment: If you tick the "Use wildcards" box and search for `.[a-zA-Z]` do you get the result you want?

Comment: According to your sample, you may try `([a-z]).([A-Z])`.

Comment: except that i'm using hebrew letters & it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @ES That was essential information... Try `.[א-ת]`. You may find it moves it over to the right of the "Find what" box. And if you're using a different symbol instead of `.`, use that, and it's possible that the punctuation will need to placed at the other end of the square brackets - I know nothing of Hebrew or how Word works with it, so a little experimentation on your part could go a long way.

Comment: Thanx I also thought of that & tried it straight away but it didn't find anything.

Comment: Excerpt: "צריך "כל", כל סכום שהוא, ולא להקפיד על הנותן אם נתן סכום קטן ממה שקצבת עליו.וזה מה שהתורה אומרת" maybe you could try on this and see if you get anything to work.

Comment: Assuming that periods aren't used in other ways you could replace all periods with space+period `' .'` then next replace all double-space+period `'  .'` with space+period `' .'`

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what tht means please can you clarify what i would gain by doing that. Thanx

Comment: @ES The search I posted earlier found the full stop in your excerpt. Are you sure that "Use wildcards" was checked when you tried it?